# java.lang.NullPointerException in click event on Selenium WebDriver com Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am receiving the error message from java.lang.NullPointerException in the click () event of SeleniumWebDriver, when I try to edit a previously registered record. The strange thing is that the script works perfectly up to a specific point which is Click (). During the execution I use the same click event on other elements without a problem. From the error message, it looks like I'm passing some null value but I don't know at what point. Can someone who has had the same problem help?

Below is the code of the classes used in automation.

**Class RunCucumberTest**

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    features = "src/test/resources/features/CrudFuncSteps.feature",
    glue = "br.com.inmetrics.teste.steps",
    tags = {"~@ignore"},
    plugin = {"pretty","html:target/report-html", "json:target/report-json"},
    monochrome = true,
    snippets=SnippetType.CAMELCASE,
    dryRun = false,
    strict = false
    )
public class RunCucumberTest {

}
```

**Class CrudFuncPage**

```
public class CrudFuncPage {

WebDriver driver;

public CrudFuncPage(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
}

private By btn_novo_funcionario = By.xpath("//*[@id=\"navbarSupportedContent\"]/ul/li[2]/a");
private By txt_nome_funcionario = By.id("inputNome");
private By txt_cpf = By.id("cpf");
private By txt_sexo = By.id("slctSexo");
private By txt_data_admmissao = By.id("inputAdmissao");
private By txt_cargo = By.id("inputCargo");
private By txt_salario = By.id("dinheiro");
private By btn_tipo_contratacao = By.id("clt");
private By btn_enviar = By.xpath("//input[@type='submit']");
private By txt_cadastrao_sucesso = By.xpath("//div[@class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show']");
private By btn_edit = By.xpath("//table[@id='tabela']/tbody/tr/td[6]/a[2]/button/span");
private By txt_validar_tela_edit_disponivel = By.xpath("//input[@type='submit']");
private By txt_alterar_cargo = By.id("inputCargo");
private By txt_validar_alteracao_cargo = By.xpath("\"//div[@class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show']\"");
private By btn_excluir_funcionario = By.id("delete-btn");
private By txt_validar_exclusao_funcionario = By
        .xpath("//div[@class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show']");



public void clicarNovoFuncionario() {
    driver.findElement(btn_novo_funcionario).click();
}

public void escreverNomeFuncionario(String nome) {
    driver.findElement(txt_nome_funcionario).sendKeys(nome);
}

public void escreverNumeroCpf(String cpf) {
    driver.findElement(txt_cpf).sendKeys(cpf);
}

public void selecionarSexo(int index) {

    WebElement elemento = driver.findElement(txt_sexo);
    Select combo = new Select(elemento);
    combo.selectByIndex(index);
}

public void escreverDataDeAdmissao(String data) {
    driver.findElement(txt_data_admmissao).sendKeys(data);
}

public void escreverCargo(String cargo) {
    driver.findElement(txt_cargo).sendKeys(cargo);
}

public void escreverSalario(String salario) {
    driver.findElement(txt_salario).sendKeys(salario);
}

public void clicarTipoContratacao() {
    driver.findElement(btn_tipo_contratacao).click();
}

public void clicarBotaoEnviar() {
    driver.findElement(btn_enviar).click();
}

public void validarCadastroComSucesso(String cadastrado) {
    String mensagem = driver.findElement(txt_cadastrao_sucesso).getText();
    Assert.assertTrue(mensagem.contains(cadastrado));
}

public void clicarBotaoEdit() {

    driver.findElement(btn_edit).click();

}

public void validarTelaEditVisivel() {
    driver.findElement(txt_validar_tela_edit_disponivel).isDisplayed();
}

public void alterarCargo(String novoCargo) {
    driver.findElement(txt_alterar_cargo).clear();
    driver.findElement(txt_alterar_cargo).sendKeys(novoCargo);
}

public void confirmarDadosEditados() {
    driver.findElement(btn_enviar).click();

}

public void validarAlteraçãoDosDadosFuncionario(String atualizada) {
    driver.findElement(btn_enviar).click();
    String mensagem = driver.findElement(txt_validar_alteracao_cargo).getText();
    Assert.assertTrue(mensagem.contains(atualizada));

}

public void clicarExcluirFuncionario() {

    driver.findElement(btn_excluir_funcionario).click();
}

public void validarExclusaoFuncionario(String removido) {

    String mensagem = driver.findElement(txt_validar_exclusao_funcionario).getText();
    Assert.assertTrue(mensagem.contains("removido"));

}

}
```

**Class CrudFuncSteps**

```
public class CrudFuncSteps {

WebDriver driver=null;
CrudFuncPage crud;

@Dado("que eu logue no sistema")
public void queEuLogueNoSistema() {

    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://www.inmrobo.tk/accounts/login/");
    driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("LeandroPereira");
    driver.findElement(By.name("pass")).sendKeys("123");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='login100-form-btn']")).click();
}

@Quando("eu clicar na opção Novo Funcionário")
public void euClicarNaOpçãoNovoFuncionário() {

    crud = new CrudFuncPage(driver);
    crud.clicarNovoFuncionario();

}

@Quando("informar o nome")
public void informarONome() {

    crud.escreverNomeFuncionario("Carlos Antonio");

}

@Quando("informar o cpf")
public void informarOCpf() {
    crud.escreverNumeroCpf("075.216.116-40");

}

@Quando("informar o sexo")
public void informarOSexo() {
    crud.selecionarSexo(3);

}

@Quando("informar a data de admissao")
public void informarADataDeAdmissao() {
    crud.escreverDataDeAdmissao("25/07/2000");

}

@Quando("informar o cargo")
public void informarOCargo() {
    crud.escreverCargo("Analista de Testes");

}

@Quando("informar o salario")
public void informarOSalario() {
    crud.escreverSalario("10000");

}

@Quando("selecionar o tipo de contratação")
public void selecionar_o_tipo_de_contratação() {
    crud.clicarTipoContratacao();

}

@Quando("clicar no botão enviar")
public void clicarNoBotãoEnviar() {
    crud.clicarBotaoEnviar();
}

@Então("o funcionário será cadastrador com sucesso")
public void o_funcionário_será_cadastrador_com_sucesso() {

    crud.validarCadastroComSucesso("cadastrado");
    
}

@Quando("eu clicar na opção edit")
public void euClicarNaOpçãoEdit() {
    //System.out.println("driver=" + driver); 
    crud.clicarBotaoEdit();
}

@Então("a tela para editar o funcionário será exibida")
public void aTelaParaEditarOFuncionárioSeráExibida() {

    crud.validarTelaEditVisivel();

}

@Quando("alterar o cargo para Analista de Testes Automatizados")
public void alterarOCargoParaAnalistaDeTestesAutomatizados() {
    crud.alterarCargo("Analista de Testes Automatizados");

}

@Quando("clicar em enviar")
public void clicarEmEnviar() {
    crud.clicarBotaoEnviar();

}

@Então("o cargo será atualizado com sucesso")
public void oCargoSeráAtualizadoComSucesso() {
    crud.validarAlteraçãoDosDadosFuncionario("atualizadas");

}

@Quando("eu clicar na opção excluir")
public void euClicarNaOpçãoExcluir() {
    crud.clicarExcluirFuncionario();

}

@Então("o sistema exclui o funcionário com sucesso")
public void oSistemaExcluiOFuncionárioComSucesso() {
    crud.validarExclusaoFuncionario("removido");

}

@After(order = 1)
public void screenshot(Scenario cenario) {
    
    File file = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    try {
        FileUtils.copyFile(file, new File("target\\screenshot\\"+cenario.getName()+".jpg"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@After (order = 0)
public void fecharBrowser() {
    driver.quit();
}
```

}

**Print with errors**

[image: Console of Eclipse]
[image: JUnit Error]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I personally think that the problem is in your variables ... to be more specific ...

```
WebDriver driver=null;
CrudFuncPage crud;
```

Later is somekinda function ...

```
crud = new CrudFuncPage(driver);
crud.clicarNovoFuncionario();
```

If you look closely ... you are just creating a new object ... same with webdriver ...

This one is acctually the same, all you did was that you specified that there is a null.

```
WebDriver driver=null;   ==    WebDriver driver;
CrudFuncPage crud;
```

My recommendation:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
CrudFuncPage crud = new CrudFuncPage(init_driver());
//    I am not sure if you can just type here ^ CrudFuncPage(driver);

public WebDriver init_driver()
{
   return driver;
}
```

by doing this, you will avoid having problems with the null ... also, if you are not using Threads, I would recommend making that driver static ... to be 100% sure that its going to be the same driver (by making it static, you can then do something like this in `"CrudFuncPage"`:

```
WebDriver driver = CrudFuncSteps.driver;
```

or you just import that driver directly from `"CrudFuncSteps"` :)

Hopefully it will fix your problem ... because by looking at it, i think there should not be a problem ... (I did not work with cucumber, so hopefully it will be fine after these changes)

Also, there is quite a few problem with a code like this...

1. I have no idea why do you have spanish decorators ... The best way to code is to use english, to avoid problems like this (i personally have no idea what is in those decorators)
2. Its nice that you provided those screenshots, but next time, please add some context to them ... i personally dont know where there is the second to last one...

P.S -> if you have any question, please let me know :) ... If I will know the answer, I will gladly help.